# What parts of R5RS are generally considered not worthwhile to implement?

Tags: scheme

I have been looking around for good, small Scheme implementations. I notice it is very usual that they claim to follow "almost all" of R5RS, but never all of it. What parts of R5RS are usually considered too hard/not worthwhile? Are they considered a mistake of R5RS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're looking for things under the too-hard/not-worthwhile category, there are several tricky details of implementing continuations in various places (and some small implementations don't have support for real continuations either).  Take a look at this (now outdated) chart that the SISC authors put together: http://sisc-scheme.org/r5rs_pitfall.php Some systems, while claiming to implement "(most) everything", have a few overlooked details like that.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few that don't implement the full numerical tower (i.e different numerical types: complex, rational, exact vs inexact numbers).

Comment: Yes... but they are not required to do that either, according to http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-9.html#%_sec_6.2.3